# Test for equality across subset of columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following df:

```
mydf <- data.frame(col1 = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Orange"),
                   col2 = c("Red", "Blue", NA, "Red"),
                   col3 = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Red"),
                   col4 = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue"))
```

I'd like to create a column called `"all_equal"` that is set to 1 if all non_NA values across columns 1-4 are equal to the same value.  This should result in the following:

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4 all_true
1    Red  Red  Red  Red     TRUE
2    Red Blue  Red  Red    FALSE
3   Blue <NA> Blue Blue     TRUE
4 Orange  Red  Red Blue    FALSE
```

Note that the NA in column two should not count against equality.  I've tried using `all` to test for equality, but it seems to not work well in dplyr chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `c_across()` with `rowwise()`.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(all_true = n_distinct(c_across(col1:col4), na.rm = T) == 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   col1   col2  col3  col4  all_true
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>   
# 1 Red    Red   Red   Red   TRUE    
# 2 Red    Blue  Red   Red   FALSE   
# 3 Blue   NA    Blue  Blue  TRUE    
# 4 Orange Red   Red   Blue  FALSE
```

Comment: Nice! The cleanest solution, yet!

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` solution could be:

```
mydf %>%
 mutate(all_equal = map_dbl(.x = transpose(select(., everything())), 
                            ~ n_distinct(na.omit(.x))) == 1)

  col1 col2 col3   col4 all_equal
1  Red Blue  Red    Red     FALSE
2  Red Blue  Red    Red     FALSE
3 Blue <NA>  Red Orange     FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can do

```
mydf$all_equal <- ifelse(apply(mydf, 1, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Output

```
#     col1 col2 col3 col4 all_equal
# 1    Red  Red  Red  Red      TRUE
# 2    Red Blue  Red  Red     FALSE
# 3   Blue <NA> Blue Blue      TRUE
# 4 Orange  Red  Red Blue     FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting this previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907539/row-wise-test-if-multiple-not-all-columns-are-equal)

```
mydf['all_true'] <- (rowSums(mydf == mydf[,1], na.rm=TRUE) + rowSums(is.na(mydf))) == ncol(mydf)
```