# Compare values in rows and identify duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, match, string-matching

I have a feeling this is a pretty simple one. I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
ID   Genre1         Genre2
1    Comedy         Comedy
2    Drama          Drama
3    Sport          Sport
4    Drama          Comedy
5    Documentary    Documentary
6    Entertainment  Entertainment
7    Film           Film
8    Drama          Crime Drama
9    Crime Drama    Drama
```

I want to identify which rows have the same values (e.g. "comedy" and "comedy") and create a new column called `match` which labels them as "yes" (or "no", for those that don't match).

Based on the sample above, the expected output should look something like this:

```
ID   Genre1         Genre2          Match
1    Comedy         Comedy          Yes
2    Drama          Drama           Yes
3    Sport          Sport           Yes
4    Drama          Comedy          No
5    Documentary    Documentary     Yes
6    Entertainment  Entertainment   Yes
7    Film           Film            Yes
8    Drama          Crime Drama     No
9    Crime Drama    Drama           No
```

Any ideas how I could go about doing this and/or what package would be best? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ifelse`:

```
df$Match <- ifelse(df$Genre1 == df$Genre2, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just to check, I have some other datasets where I need to run this on which have more than just two columns. Some have four. Could this solution be adapted to work for those?

Comment: As in to say if all four columns are the same? You could technically do that by altering the condition with something like `df$Genre 1 == df$Genre2 & df$Genre2 == df$Genre3 & df$Genre3 == df$Genre4` but that's pretty ugly. You could maybe try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907539/row-wise-test-if-multiple-not-all-columns-are-equal

Comment: Nice, glad it helped!